# Selenium command button click not working || PrimeFaces

Tags: java, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

Click on Command button of primefaces is not working while testing it for selenium,
My sample code is :

```
WebElement btnSaveSchedule= driver.findElement(By.id("j_idt70:btnSave"));
   btnSaveSchedule.click();
```

I have also tried :

```
        btnSaveSchedule.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
        btnSaveSchedule.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        btnSaveSchedule.submit();
```

Moreover, this button is on prime faces dialaog box appearing fine.Strange thing is that no error occurred, but no call at server , i have verified by debugging also.. Please advice

Comment: If the button appears in some other window, you need to switch it.  I don't quite get what you mean when you say "his button is on prime faces dialaog box appearing fine."  Is there some html or site you can point to for demo?

Comment: I mean to say button is present at html, and no exception while finding it by Id in selenium.

Comment: Maybe the button that you are trying to click is not fully loaded yet..Are you getting any error messages?